# Forwarding ports for RDP with SBS 2012

Tags: port-forwarding, windows-sbs, d-link

I am having issues forwarding ports on a D-Link DIR-615 router. I have a Windows Server 2012 Essentials set up, including the Remote Web Access (which works properly!). The problem originally is that my client wants to be able to access their PC from outside the network via their iPhones. If I just go to the `https://company.remotewebaccess.com` address, the iPhones display just the remote files. Of course, on a PC, they can log in and choose their PC to connect to.

I then thought about forwarding the ports for each PC, and setting up an App on their iPhones with the information put in already. I left the default port `3389` for the Server, then I incremented by one: `3390` for `UserA`, `3391` for `UserB`, etc. I then set the Private ports in the router page to `3389` and the static IP address of the clients, but each App I try (even from a Windows PC outside the network) tells me `This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator`.

[image]

I then thought about [changing the port in the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306759), but I'm worried it will break the Remote Web Access version of the RDP. So the question is: **Should I change the registry port number on each PC, or can I setup port forwarding another way in the router?**

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems in the past with some residential routers such as D-Link with port address translation done in this fashion. It *should* work in theory, but it does not always work. I have had more luck changing the listening port on the local workstation. You can always try it on a test workstation for troubleshooting purposes.

Another more expensive, more impactful option would be to upgrade your router to an enterprise grade firewall such as a [Cisco ASA](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/index.html).

Comment: Or for the more budget-conscious, pfSense running on a spare server (free) or a PCEngines ALIX board (cheap ~$120).